# How can I exclude an entity type from a query result

Tags: ravendb

Given the following multi-map index, how can I exclude entities of type `TypeA` from a query?

Index:

```
AddMap<TypeA>(docs => from doc in docs
                      select new
                      {
                          doc.Title,
                          doc.DatePublished,
                          Query = new object[]
                          {
                              doc.Title,
                              doc.Body,
                              doc.Tags
                          }
                      });

AddMap<TypeB>(docs => from doc in docs
                      select new
                      {
                          doc.Title,
                          doc.DatePublished,
                          Query = new object[]
                          {
                              doc.Title,
                              doc.Body,
                              doc.Tags
                          }
                      });

Index("@metadata.Raven-Entity-Name", FieldIndexing.Default);
```

I've tried

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<ISharedInterface, IndexType>()
                .Not.WhereEquals("@metadata.Raven-Entity-Name", 
                 Session.Advanced.DocumentStore
                        .Conventions.GetTypeTagName(typeof(TypeA)));
```

But I get the error

> The field '@metadata.Raven-Entity-Name' is not indexed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add that field to the mapping function:

```
select new {
    ...
    Tag = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"],
    ...
}
```

Add that to both maps, and you can then remove the Index() line.

See http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/document-metadata

Comment: Thanks, does it have to be called `Tag`?

Comment: Cool, querying in Raven Studio `Tag:TypeAs` works, but when I try to negate the condition, `-Tag:TypeAs`, no results are returned. Any idea? The index is not stale.

Comment: If this is the only clause, you need to have a positive clause as well